# How much is it necessary for Muslims to learn Arabic?

Tags: practical-islam, arabic

It is clear that all of the Muslims of the world are not Arab people. Perhaps approximately a milliard of Muslims across the world are non-Arab (as non-Arabic languages), as a result, probably, majority of them are not familiar with Arabic language.

So, as you probably know, the holy Qur'an and also traditions are in Arabic. Is there any Hadith ( or any verse of Qur'an) that mentioned the significance of learning Arabic for non-Arab Muslims?

Comment: Just a million? According to Google, the population of Iran is over 77 million, and the majority of those are non-Arab Muslims.

Comment: @Daniel, well done, you cared about a nice point! I edited it. actually the right word was 1 milliard which I wrote it 1 million. God bless you for pointing such a significant statistical wrong.

Comment: In the mean while, yeah, Majority of Iran population is non-Arab. Actually perhaps there are approximately 2 or 3 million Arab(S) in Iran. (that majority of them are in Khuzestan province and also in Ahvaz city.) Good luck mate.

Comment: One simple line, the reason why we should strive to learn Arabic is because, Qur'an is in Arabic, we offer our Salah, in Arabic. So, to get the real feel, it is highly advisable to learn Arabic.

Comment: Oh, yeah, precisely, it is a very significant issue which u said " So, to get the real feel, it is highly advisable to learn Arabic.". Nice reason @servantofWiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                                     In the name of Allah
```

**الحمدلله خلق الانسان علَّمه البیان نَزَّل القرآن بلسان عربیّ مبین، و الصلاة و السلام علی النبیّ العربیّ سیّد ولد آدم و خاتم الانبیاء و المرسلین**

As far as I searched, there is no tradition to point that it is considered as a Wajib (mandatory) act for Muslim, but there are some items which make us learning Arabic. For instance by learning Arabic, perhaps we can comprehend the Quran better which is in Arabic, or in reading the origin Ahadith and so on.

On the other hand, Arabic language is counted as one of the most populous language and according to my research, Arabic is considered as the Sixth language of the world (from the aspect of the population).

There is a tradition from Imam Ali (peace be upon him) that said:

> « تَعـَلـَّموا العَرَبیّــﮥ و عَـلِّـموها النّاسَ .  Learn Arabic and
>   teach it to the people.

Or  Imam Sadiq (a.s.) said:

> تَـعَـلَّـموا العَرَبیّــﮥَ فَـإنَّـها کلامُ اللهِ الَّـذی
>   یُـکَـلِّـمُ بِـهِ خَـلْـقَـهُ .
>
> Learn Arabic, because this is the speech of the God who speaks to his
>   creatures.

Even Imam Khomeini has illustrate concerning the significance of learning Arabic:

> Do not say that Arabic is not from us, Arabic language is from us,
>   Arabic language is the language of Islam and Islam is for all people.

**It could be considered from other aspects such as:**

- Being able to speak with Arab Muslims in interchanging the Islamic
  knowledge and civilizations and so forth.
- Being able to have discussion with other Muslims (Arabs) regarding
  Islamic issues such as Quran, hadiths and so forth.
- Being able to watching other Islamic Arabic channels of TV and radio 
  and obtaining Islamic and scientific revenue by watching and hearing 
  them.
- Finally it could be a more unity between Muslims in different
  languages.

---

**Reference(s):**

- [www.iranvij.ir](http://www.iranvij.ir/73724/10)
- [ali-shabab.blogfa.com](http://ali-shabab.blogfa.com/post/7)

Comment: Now a days we have so many translations, we can easily read the translation and understand it better that way. As for communication between Arabs and non-Arabs, I do not think non-Arabs need to learn a second international language in order to communicate with other nations. Learning Arabic just seems important for scholars, not for common people.

Comment: @user1204089, I agree u somewhat, what it could be better for the readers to be familiar with Arabic in order to read the original Islamic texts rather than referring to its translations, Since occasionally the translation caanot convey the precise meaning..

Comment: Furtheremore, occasionally it won't be so confident to refer to every translated text... anyhow as I uttered, I agree to u to some extent... well done, that u paid attention to the mentioned issue. Good luck.

Comment: okay, I agree with this. Ability to interpret original text can be useful.

Answer (score -1):

There is no indication that it is compulsory to learn Arabic. All of the foreign sahabah (Salman the Persian, Bilal the Abyssinian, and Suhayb the Roman) were bilingual and probably translated Islamic statements into their respective languages for their people. I have heard that Salman al-Farsi translated the first Surah into Persian (Farsi).

Comment: nice answer. It can be more helpful if you add some references

Comment: Yeah, as @blackfyre declareed, ur reply would be nicer by adding some sources. Anyhow tis a nice and logical reply.